# How to export X and Y plot values from an R plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, survival-analysis

Using the eha and survival packages in R, I am using the following code to create the survival plot below:

```
with(dataset, plot(Surv(enter, exit, event), ylim= c(0.87, 1.0), fn = "surv", strata = Gender))
```

[image]

Rather than exporting the image of the plot, how can I export the X and Y values for each line on this plot? I attempted to use the following code, however it only creates a blank .csv file:

```
write.table((with(dataset, plot(Surv(enter, exit, event), ylim= c(0.87, 1.0), fn = "surv", strata = Gender))), file="testfit.csv", sep=',')
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

On a secondary note, does anyone happen to know how to make this plot look nicer in ggplot2?

Comment: Why would you plot an object and then try to pull the values from the plot??? Pull the values from the object itself! `my_surv = with(dataset, Surv(enter, exit, event))`. Then see `?survfit` or `?plot.survfit`

Comment: `ggfortify` has nice survival plots http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_surv

Comment: I don't follow you, @Gregor. In both ?survfit and ?plot.survift, I don't see options for pulling the values from the object itself.

Comment: They're in there all the same. Looking a little more closely, I actually think the `summary.survfit` object is what's easiest to get them out of. Using the example from `?summary.survfit`, `x = summary( survfit( Surv(futime, fustat)~1, data=ovarian)); head(x)`, you'll see `x` has both `time` and `surv` components.

Comment: @Gregor, thank you. Yes, `summary(survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data=dataset))` outputs what I need.  
  
My next challenge is exporting to a .csv. `write.table(summary(survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data=dataset)), file="testfit.csv", sep=',')` throws "cannot coerce class ""summary.survfit"" to a data.frame", and when I try to stratify with `summary(survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, subset=(Gender==M), data=dataset))`, RStudio returns "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'M' not found"

Comment: Assign the summary and use the components of the summary to build the data frame you want. `x = summary(...); str(x)`.

Comment: See, e.g., [Obtaining Survival Estimates in R](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9537026/903061).

Comment: Appreciate the help, @Gregor. I wish I understood why `as.data.frame(summary(survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data=dataset)))` again throws "cannot coerce class ""summary.survfit"" to a data.frame".

Comment: `x = summary(survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data=dataset)); str(x)` produces the below results. Do these indicate how to coerce class to a data.frame?  

`List of 15
 $ n: int 
 $ time: num
 $ n.risk: num
 $ n.event: num
 $ n.censor: num
 $ n.enter: num
 $ surv: num
 $ type: chr "counting"
 $ std.err: num
 $ upper: num
 $ lower: num
 $ conf.type: chr "log"
 $ conf.int : num 0.95
 $ call: language survfit(formula = Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data = dataset)
 $ table: Named num
..- attr(*, "names")= chr "records" "n.max" "n.start" "events" ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr "summary.survfit"`

Comment: @Gregor, I've done as you suggested and assigned the summary `fit <- survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data=dataset)` and as in [Obtaining...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535668/obtaining-survival-estimates-in-r/9537026#9537026) I've tried to coerce to data frame with `as.data.frame(summary(fit)[c("time", "survival")])`. The error being thrown now is _Error in data.frame(time = c(.1, .2, .5, .6, .8, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 74, 0_. Now what should I do?

Comment: Maybe make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)? Can you share some data or find built-in data with similar structure that generates the same error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gridGraphics package to convert your plot to a grob, then grab the points from out of the grob object. I like this solution because it is applicable to a wide range of problems.

Using the graph that was created [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/07/creating-good-looking-survival-curves-the-ggsurv-function/) for an example graph:

```
# plot a graph
library(survival)
library(grid)
library(gridGraphics)
data(lung)
lung.surv <- survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ 1, data = lung)
plot(lung.surv)

# capture the plotted output as a grob
grid.echo()
grid.grab() -> k

# pull out the data from the grob..
k$children$`graphics-plot-1-points-1`$x -> x
k$children$`graphics-plot-1-points-1`$y -> y
```

I noticed that your plot is stratified by gender...Make sure you pull out the correct subset of the points for each gender.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. This modified code still generates my survival curve per your template above:

    data.surv <- survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, data = dataset)

And now that I've entered the rest of your code, how do I access/export the X and Y values?

Also I'm not sure how to stratify by gender. I've tried this code below, but the plot ends up with just a horizontal line and then a vertical line instead of a normal survival curve:

    data.surv <- survfit(Surv(enter, exit, event) ~ 1, subset=(Gender), data = dataset)

How should I be subsetting?

Comment: What dataset are you using and what is the purpose of the analysis? If you're trying to plot a new survival curve with the x and y values, I would recommend using ggfortify